# setImeOptions not working consistently

Tags: android, android-edittext

We have two EditText - A & B. EditText A is always visible and B is visible or hidden based on certain conditions. Here is how we use setImeOptions

To hide B,

```
B.setVisibility(View.GONE);    
A.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO);
```

To show B

```
B.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);    
A.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);
B.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO);
```

B is password field and both the EditText has android:singleLine="true"

Above code is executed based on certain conditions. The problem is that, after B is visible and if we click on EditText A, it still shows 'Go' button instead of 'Next'. However, if we click on B and then click on A, it shows 'Next' as expected.

Any idea what's going wrong?

Comment: Can you please let us know in which event/events you are doing hide/show of b?

Comment: Post your code please

Answer (score 4):

You probably need to change the focus of `EditText` to elsewhere whenever you change the state of `EditText`s. If the focus is still on any of the `EditText` while changing the attributes, it won't reflect in the keyboard.

Comment: Thank you ! This was the reason it didn't work for me. I was working with a searchview in the action bar.